# How to run a web url script in a terminal

Tags: command-line, bash

I am attempting to launch a script via my terminal. It runs fine in my browser but not in the terminal.

Ive tried...

```
sudo curl https://www.example.com/myscript?info=1

sudo wget -q -O- https://www.example.com/myscript?info=1

sudo wget https://www.example.com/myscript?info=1
```

Here is the output I get...

```
[2] 25034
[1]   Done
```

But I know its not working because part of the code sends an email, this email gets sent when I run the url from a browser, but fails to do so when ran from the terminal.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems you have `&` somewhere in your url, hence the shell is sending the process to background.

To solve this, quote the url.

For example, if you use :

```
curl https://www.example.com/myscript/foo&bar
```

the shell will treat the url as `https://www.example.com/myscript/foo` and `&` after that will cause the `curl https://www.example.com/myscript/foo` process to go background. Note that `bar` after `&` is missing too.

So you need to quote the url :

```
curl 'https://www.example.com/myscript/foo&bar'
curl "https://www.example.com/myscript/foo&bar"
```

Also note that `?` has a special meaning to shell (means any single character), so when you have shell meta-characters anywhere in your argument you should quote the argument (unless intentional).

Comment: Thank you, +1 for spotting that I had `&` without me including it in my post :)

Comment: @Adrian whenever you see `[2] 25034 [1] Done` something like that it typically means shell has sent some process to background..so now you get the idea  :)